# Explode in Spark missing records

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Existing Schema of the DF:

```
|-- col1: string (nullable = true)
|-- col2: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- col2_1: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- col2_2: string (nullable = true)
```

Example data for the existing Schema:

```
 col1         col2    
  A       [[0,2],[1,3]]
  B       [[1,5]] 
  C       [[5,9],[4,6],[2,6]]
```

Required Schema:

```
|-- col1: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- col2_1: string (nullable = true)
|-- col2_2: string (nullable = true)
```

Example data for required Schema:

```
 col1          col2_1    col2_2    
  A            0           2
  A            1           3
  B            1           5
  C            5           9
  C            4           6
  C            2           6
```

Code:

```
var df_flattened = df.select($"*", explode($"col2").as("flat")).select($"*",$"flat.col2_1",$"flat.col2_2").drop("col2")
```

I am not getting any errors with the code. but its missing values from the original DF, where the distinct(col1) is ~20000 in the original and it changes to ~6000 after the flattening.

Any suggestions on the mistake.

Comment: Can the array in `col2` be empty?

Comment: @ollik1 No it cannot be empty. But it can have variable size like in the example above.

Comment: @ollik1 You are right. the value of col2 was null in some cases and those records were missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`explode()` will not emit any rows where the array being exploded is `null`. Therefore, you should use `explode_outer()` instead.